# com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=503 in firebase Login Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, firebase

I have integrated firebase authentication for login and signup. 
But I am getting a below error while authentication

> com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=503 
>   Request Authorization Header Missing or Malformed

But when I checked in firebase there is an already entry for the user which I created using signup. So the login and signed up is being validated, but I am getting above 503 error.

Is there anything I am missing in configuration of firebase of something required to be added in App setting or plist

-Thanks in advance
 Aakil